# Trying to create a function in phpmyAdmin from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, function, phpmyadmin

I need to create a function in phpmyadmin but it's always returning an error. I have a table of products, where shows the prices as 'PRECIO' and I need to add the taxes to them, here is the code:

```
create FUNCTION CalcularIva
(preciototal decimal(8,3))
RETURNS decimal(8,3)
BEGIN
DECLARE preciototal decimal(8,3)
    select NOMBREARTÍCULO, PRECIO
    from `productos`
    where PRECIO=@precio
    set @preciototal=(@precio*1,21)
    return @preciototal
end
```

The error says this:
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'select NOMBREARTÍCULO, PRECIO
from `productos`
where PRECIO=@precio
...' en la linea 6

Here you can see the table I have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvvMB.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably missing a terminator just before the `SELECT` keyword.  `DECLARE preciototal decimal(8,3);` Notice the semicolon. Depending on client, sometimes the DELIMITER change is required as well.

Comment: What is `@precio` used in the `WHERE` clause, as I do not see that defined anywhere? (maybe `precio` is the input parameter?) Anyway, a semi-colon is needed where mentioned in the previous comment and also at the end of the select statement, and at the end of the set statement, and the end of the return statement. I didn't see that `NOMBREARTÍCULO` is used either, but I modified the select, set, and return to: `select PRECIO into preciototal
    from \`productos\`
    where PRECIO=@precio;
    set @preciototal=(@preciototal*1,21);
    return preciototal;`